# calculations on floating number nowhere near correct

Tags: php, floating-point, int

I have a script that works out the instalments for a period of time again an amount.

Straight forward correct? well apparently not according to php.

Here is the posted form information, I know this is what is being posted because I am var_dump() all post values to make sure that is what is being posted.

```
array
    'total' => string string '999,999.99' (length=10)
    'howmany' => string '16,666.67' (length=9)
    'installmentcost1' => string '999,999.99' (length=10)
```

This is the very simple php formula

```
$tempInstallments = (intval($_POST['howmany'])) - 1; // get 1 less so we can make sure the last payment is within total amount
$tempInstallmentCost = (floatval($_POST['installmentcost1'])) * $tempInstallments; //installment price * the installment period minus 1 month
$tempTotal = floatval($_POST['cpototal']) - $tempInstallmentCost; // get the final payment cost
```

Now unfortunately this is for some reason giving me some really bad math which I am var_dump() out also.

Here is the var_dump I am using:

```
var_dump($tempInstallments);
var_dump($_POST['installmentcost1']);
var_dump($tempInstallmentCost);
var_dump($tempTotal);
```

Here is what is dumped out:

```
int 59
string '16,666.67' (length=9)
float 944
float 55
```

As you can see they are not even close to the actual information that is needed.

For instance it is meant to look like the following:

```
int 59
string '16,666.67' (length=9)
float 983,333.53 (length=10)
float 16,666.46 (length=9)
```

Any Ideas why this is happening. I am even making sure that the information is a definite float or int.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`intval()` and `floatval()` don't handle punctuation, so `intval("1,234.56")` is `1`. You can use `filter_var()` instead:

```
$s = '1,234.56';
var_dump(filter_var($s, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION));
```

This yields:

```
string(7) "1234.56"
```

Which you can then `intval()` or `floatval()` if needed. Or just strip commas:

```
$s = '1,234.56';
$s = str_replace(',', '', $s);
var_dump(floatval($s));
```

Comment: Thanks ,did not occur to me that the comma would not read considering it was php that put them in there to start with.